# SQL YTD and last year YTD on complete data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to calculate YTD and last year YTD on a table [SQL Server 2012]. Below is the query I tried. Its getting doubled and tripled for some cases.

```
SELECT SUM(A.RevisionNumber)YTD,SUM(P.RevisionNumber)LY_YTD,B.OrderDateM,B.OrderDateY
FROM
    (select MONTH(OrderDate)OrderDateM,YEAR(OrderDate)OrderDateY from sales.SalesOrderHeader B
    group by MONTH(OrderDate),YEAR(OrderDate))B
 LEFT JOIN
    (select SUM(RevisionNumber)RevisionNumber,MONTH(OrderDate)OrderDateM,YEAR(OrderDate)OrderDateY
    from sales.SalesOrderHeader
    group by MONTH(OrderDate),YEAR(OrderDate))A
 ON A.OrderDateM<=B.OrderDateM AND A.OrderDateY=B.OrderDateY
 LEFT JOIN
    (select SUM(RevisionNumber)RevisionNumber,MONTH(OrderDate)OrderDateM,YEAR(OrderDate)OrderDateY
    from sales.SalesOrderHeader
    group by MONTH(OrderDate),YEAR(OrderDate))P
 ON P.OrderDateM<=B.OrderDateM AND P.OrderDateY=B.OrderDateY-1
GROUP BY B.OrderDateM,B.OrderDateY
ORDER BY B.OrderDateY,B.OrderDateM
```

[image]

Comment: Adding sample data as image is not going to help you.. Nobody can use it to the test the queries. Add sample data as text in table format.. 68 questions with 7 years of time in SO you should be knowing this..

Comment: If the values are exactly double and triple then it is a pretty good sign that you're query is returning multiple rows for some of your groupings. This is usually a sign that the join predicates are not correct. We can't possibly provide any kind of detail since you didn't provide any for us. Here is a great place to start. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: The first join returns *n* rows for the *nth* months and the 2nd joins those `n` months to another `n` months, i.e. correct for january, twice for February, triple for March, etc. Quick & dirty solution: divide `LY_YTD` by the month number. Clean solution: Rewrite to two Selects (current & last year) and outer join them.

Comment: @dnoeth I rewrote query with two selects and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use windowing function as below:

```
;With cte as (
    Select Sum(RevisionNumber) As SM_RevisionNumber, Month(OrderDate) as OrderM,
           Year(OrderDate) as OrderY
           From Sales.SalesOrderHeader
           Group by Month(OrderDate), Year(OrderDate)
        ), cte2 as (
    Select YTD = Sum(SM_RevisionNumber) over (partition by OrderY order by OrderM),
        OrderM, OrderY, RowN = Row_Number() over(order by OrderY, OrderM)
        from cte
    )
    Select YTD, LY_YTD = lag(YTD, 12, null) over(Order by RowN), OrderM, ORderY
        from cte2
```

But this solution assumes we have atleast one entry for each month and year.